# How to Register<Func<Type, IEnumerable<T>> in simple injector

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I am trying to implement cqrs to my system and How can i register Generic collection in simple injector? When i trying what i run my code i got exception Please use one of the other overloads to register this type.

```
public class Ioc
  {
      public static SimpleInjector.Container Container;

      static Ioc()
      {
          Container = new SimpleInjector.Container();

          Container.Register<IHandleEvent, Handler>(Lifestyle.Transient);
          Container.Register<ICommandsBus, CommandsBus(Lifestyle.Transient);
          Container.Register<IEventsBus, EventsBus>(Lifestyle.Transient);
          Container.Register<Func<Type, IEnumerable<IHandleEvent>>> (Lifestyle.Transient);
      }
  }

//Without any Conatiner working

List<Handler> handlers = new List<Handler>();
          Handler handler = new Handler();
          handlers.Add(handler);
          Func<Type, IEnumerable<IHandleEvent>> func = f => handlers;
          EventsBus eventsBus = new EventsBus(func);
          eventsBus.Publish(new User { Id = 1, Login = "Test" });

// I want something like this
 var bus = Ioc.Container.GetInstance<IEventsBus>();
          bus.Publish(new User { Id = 1, Login = "tt" });
```

Comment: Please explain what it is you are trying to achieve. Do you want to register a collection of `IHandleEvent` implementations? And if so, who do you wish to determine which `IHandleEvent` implementation handles which type of event? You are publishing `User`, but which handler should handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your handlers are generics you can try add them with the following logic, firstly get them with GetTypesToRegister and then register as a collection

```
  // assemblies - assemblies with your handlers 

var notificationHandlerTypes = 
    Container.GetTypesToRegister(typeof(IHandleEvent<>), assemblies, new 
        TypesToRegisterOptions
        {
            IncludeGenericTypeDefinitions = true,
            IncludeComposites = false,
        });
Container.Collection.Register(typeof(IHandleEvent<>), notificationHandlerTypes);
```

Comment: Your registration can be simplified to `Container.Collection.Register(typeof(IHandleEvent<>), assemblies);` (with the difference that generic type definitions will not be registered, but that would typically not be a problem).